# How to use objects in Python to perform a function and obtain an answer?

Tags: python, oop, optimization

I am new to Python and oop. For a research I'm trying to pass Python objects formed using excel data to a function and get the answers and find the minimum.  I have created the objects from excel data to a dictionary but I don't understand how to proceed with the function.

Ex: I have 4 different types of containers with different attributes.

```
Type  Investment($) Lifespan 

T1        20           10   
T2        30            25   
T3        10            7    
T4        15            8
```

The dictionary looks like this.

```
{'T1' : {'Investment' : 20, 'Lifespan' : 10}, 'T2' : {'Investment' : 30, 'Lifespan' : 25}, 'T3' : {'Investment' : 10, 'Lifespan' : 7}, 'T4':{'Investment' : 15, 'Lifespan' : 8}}
```

So I need to calculate the life cycle cost of each type using LCC equation which is predefined and to find the minimum answer (This is just a simple version and the research is bit bigger in scope). I don't understand how I need to pass the objects dictionary to the function and to get the minimum. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking a complex question that requires multiple steps. In order to get the minimum value out of your dict you could try this, which will return the minimum value form the 'Lifespan' data.

Pass your dictionary object to the function.

```
def get_min(your_dict):
    a = []
    for _T, T_data in investments.items():
        a.append(T_data.get('Lifespan'))
    return min(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might not have heard of lambdas before but they could be pretty useful here.

```py
def minItem(d: dict):
    return min(d, key=lambda k: d[k]['Lifespan'])
```

This will sort a dictionary based on your sub-dictionary's `'Lifespan'` key. `k` is the key of each dictionary item (i.e. `'T1'`, `'T2'`, ...). Accessing `d[k]['Lifespan']` tells Python to find the minimum *based on that particular key*. Thus, it will compare `d['T1']['Lifespan']`, `d['T2']['Lifespan']`, ... to sort each item, finding the least element.

```py
>>> def minItem(d: dict):
        return min(d, key=lambda k: d[k]['Lifespan'])

>>> data={'T1' : {'Investment' : 20, 'Lifespan' : 10}, 'T2' : {'Investment' : 30, 'Lifespan' : 25}, 'T3' : {'Investment' : 10, 'Lifespan' : 7}, 'T4':{'Investment' : 15, 'Lifespan' : 8}}
>>> minItem(data)
T3
>>> data[minItem(data)]
{'Investment': 10, 'Lifespan': 7}
```